# Jquery sortable grid widget rollover effect

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make the process smoother using css transitions.

So when a tile is moved it disappears then fades back in once in position.

For the sake of simplicity I have changed my example code to just transition in a font color change

The issue that I have it that i am trying to get this affect every tile that moves, not just the immediate one to the right

Try as I might I dont seem to be able to re-trigger the effect in one mouse movement.

If works ok if I stop and re-drag but not across all items which move during the drag.
(I hope that make sense!)

My html is here

```
<ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">12</li></ul>
```

my js is here

```
$(function () {
$("#sortable").sortable({
    sort: function (event, ui) {
        changeit = ui.item.nextAll('li.ui-state-default').eq(0);
        changeit.css({
            'color': 'blue',
                '-webkit-transition': 'color 0.5s ease-in',
                '-moz-transition': 'color 0.5s ease-in',
                '-o-transition': 'color 0.5s ease-in',
                'transition': 'color 0.5s ease-in'
        })
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

});

and my css is here

```
   #sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 450px;
}

    .sortable li {
        margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
        padding: 1px;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 90px;
        font-size: 4em;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I have set a fiddle up here
http://jsfiddle.net/mw8Xu/21/

I am keeping my fingers crossed someone can help as i am at my wits end!

thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an update to this.... 
I have managed to do this... http://jsfiddle.net/7TgBe/3/
but i am unsure how to stop everything from shifting around.... any ideas ? thanks in advance